# Some other domain showing my exact site?

Tags: dns, cross-domain

I used the site called http://get-site-ip.com/ to get the IP and both the results are showing me the same result.
[This is the search result where my site is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFXPT.png)

This http://shoulderdoc.in is my original domain
My site shouldn't be at http://brainolam.com/

[Bainolam result where my site shouldn't be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MuJx.png)

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because on your web server, you have not mentioned the hostname for which this site should work. You need to create a virtualhost entry with your hostname.

Currently anyone can point a domain with the ip address - 97.74.236.109, will show your website.

Comment: why negative voting?